# gpu partially detected, torch tensor is not uploaded to gpu

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

My gpu is detected on

```
torch.cuda.is_available()

torch.randn(1).cuda()

tensorflow.test.is_built_with_cuda()

torch.cuda.device_count()
```

but not on

```
device_lib.list_local_devices()

tensorflow.config.list_local_devices('GPU')
```

the code I used is:

```
print(torch.cuda.is_available())

print(torch.randn(1).cuda())

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())

print(tf.__version__)

print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
```

and the result is:

```
True
tensor([0.7429], device='cuda:0')
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 11914755976629927437
xla_global_id: -1
]
True
2.10.0
[]
cuda:0
1
```

I'm using NVIDIA GTX 1070 Ti, Nvidia graphics driver 460.89, cuda 11.2, cudnn 8.1.1, torch 1.7.1+cu110, torchvision 0.8.2+cu110.

Although the result above, my deeplearning model successfully got in cuda. The problem is that I cannot get my tensor data to gpu.
When I checked the datatype with `print(type(x))`, it returned `<class 'torch.Tensor'>`.

I then tried both `x.to(device)` and `x.cuda()`.

But in both cases, it returns false to `x.is_cuda`.

When I tried to make this data go through my model, it returned this:
`RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same`

Which means my model is on gpu. I can't figure out why my tensor is on cpu but my model isn't.

My data is a tensor converted from image, and is a shape of [3, 3, 512, 512].
My model is a GAN.

Comment: Do not describe code, actually include the code that produces the problem. There is no such thing as partial detecting of a GPU, it does not make sense to compare Tensorflow and PyTorch here since they need different CUDA setup, so there could be differences there.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.

I didn't reassign x.

In case someone bump into this, using `x = x.cuda()` instead of `x.cuda()` made it fixed.

Comment: This is exactly why including code is mandatory, you might make mistakes that we are not aware of.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy yeah, thanks for two comments you gave me after this. I'm quite new here, so I guess I'm making every possible mistakes. But I did really include all my codes above without any character lost, and I really think someone could notice I wrote ```x.to(device)``` not ```x = x.to(device)```. I'll try to include all the codes next time, if that's not against to my confidentiality contract, thanks to your advice.